# How to put dynamic value and save it in HashMap?

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a method that generates me a new String streamName and String key value every 10 seconds. I would like all these values to be written to the hashMap, but unfortunately I still have one current value. How can I save to hashmap data which is generated only for some time and add new values to make a list with all values? I have no idea how can I do it

I put values on this way:

```
HashMap<String, String> streamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
streamMap.put(streamName, key);
```

Comment: Your code save value to map correctly.

Comment: But I want to have all values not only one actual value

Comment: Call `streamMap.put(streamName, key);` for all of them

Answer (score 0):

## Understanding maps, a collection of key-value entries

The fact that you put `key` as your second argument indicates that you may misunderstand the purpose of a `Map` in Java. A map holds a collection entries, each entry being a pairing of a key to a value. For example:

```
Map< String , String > favoriteColorsByPerson = new HashMap<>() ;
favoriteColorsByPerson.put( "Alice" , "Purple" ) ;
favoriteColorsByPerson.put( "Bob" , "Black" ) ;
```

If you do a `put` for Bob again, you replace the existing entry.

```
favoriteColorsByPerson.put( "Bob" , "Chartreuse" ) ;  // Replaces the previous entry for Bob.
```

After than line, the "Black" value is gone. Bob's new favorite color is [Chartreuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartreuse_(color)).

You do not present enough detail to know for sure, but I suspect you are saving different values to the same key, the same `streamName`. If `streamName` never changes while you call `put` repeatedly, you are replacing the existing value (in 2nd argument) with a new value.

## Example demo code

Here is an example of collecting some map entries overtime. I use `Instant` as the key, and a random UUID as the value.

We use a concurrent map, in case we decide to access the map across threads.

We use a navigable map, to maintain the entries in order of their keys. This means effectively chronological order given that our keys are `Instant` objects.

```
ConcurrentNavigableMap < Instant, UUID > map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap <>();
```

We set up a `ScheduledExecutorService` to handle executing our task.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

We define our task as a `Runnable` using lambda syntax. You could just as well use conventional syntax if not yet familiar with lambdas and functional coding.

```
Runnable task = () -> map.put( Instant.now() , UUID.randomUUID() );
```

We ask the executor service to execute our task repeatedly, once every 10 seconds approximately.

```
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , 0 , 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
```

We wait a minute to let our demo have a chance to run. So we expect to see around 6 or 7 entries in our map; 1 minute = 60 seconds, divided by 10 is 6.

```
try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes(1).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Then we attempt to shutdown our executor service.

```
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

We wait up to another minute for that service to shut down.

```
try { scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Then we dump our map to console.

```
System.out.println( "map = " + map );
```

Put that all together.

```java
System.out.println( "Demo starting. " + Instant.now() );

ConcurrentNavigableMap < Instant, UUID > map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap <>();
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Runnable task = () -> map.put( Instant.now() , UUID.randomUUID() );
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , 0 , 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );

try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes( 1 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
try { scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
System.out.println( "map = " + map );

System.out.println( "Demo ending. " + Instant.now() );
```

When run:

```
Demo starting. 2021-08-05T02:40:55.391301Z
map = {2021-08-05T02:40:55.400890Z=7d335b7e-2ca7-4e35-9595-fd875da875ff, 2021-08-05T02:41:05.405338Z=514e7a94-1e0a-4167-8b86-b0ed715abe5b, 2021-08-05T02:41:15.404927Z=737bc7a3-2a96-4107-b34f-c234771c4509, 2021-08-05T02:41:25.402508Z=0029c81e-c7c5-46da-b984-408f786bc3c9, 2021-08-05T02:41:35.406593Z=03f35ac3-9e41-46e7-b902-1e1c1372da60, 2021-08-05T02:41:45.403105Z=d0119ced-ecf7-481c-aee6-f7156215ef0e, 2021-08-05T02:41:55.401486Z=ce0b7231-480a-4438-9202-ab7f4bebeeef}
Demo ending. 2021-08-05T02:41:55.406882Z
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I wanted to get a map like this=[live=2daf2e402a063a5622dbf3cca2e411e8, live1=51535a9384ab61905a393f436391146b] I should put two String in map

Comment: When I replaced map.put( Instant.now() , UUID.randomUUID() ); to ->map.put( key.toString() , streamName.toString() ); it didn't work

Comment: @Julia You have not explained what is `key` or `streamName` in your code, nor have explained why you need to call `toString` rather than use a map of those types. And you have not addressed the main issue I raised: Putting the same key with different values. How could any of us possibly help you further?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I should actually share more of the code but I fixed that, in fact the problem was that the map had to be static because I kept creating a new one all the time -> static HashMap<String, String> streamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you generate a new key for a stream, every 10 seconds.

Streamname stays the same, key-value changes every 10 seconds.

Using a `HashMap<String, String>` in combination with `map.put(streamName, key)`, it will always have the most recent value. That is correct.

What you want to have is a Map like `Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();`

```java
List<String> keyValueList = map.computeIfAbscent(streamName, name -> new ArrayList<>());
keyValueList.add(key);
```

This will create entries like

```
"StreamA" -> ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
"StreamB" -> ["CCC", "DDD"]
```

Comment: @Julia: Did it help?